# How to add dynamically control when checkbox in datagridview is checked vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, checkbox, dynamic, datagridview

**I tired for this** 
How to add dynamically textbox, label, and form from checkbox in datagridview? 
this is my code

```
Sub getDataWIP()
    dgvbool = False
    D_DATA.Columns.Clear()
    Dim dt As DataTable = getData("SELECT created_at AS 'TANGGAL', assy_code AS 'ASSY CODE', model AS 'MODEL', lot_no AS 'LOT NUMBER',  " &
                                   "remark AS 'REMARK', qty AS QTY, shift AS SHIFT, pic AS PIC " &
                                   "FROM WIP_AUTO")
    D_DATA.DataSource = dt
    Dim checkBoxColumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
    checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = ""
    checkBoxColumn.Width = 30
    checkBoxColumn.Name = "checkBoxColumn"
    D_DATA.Columns.Insert(0, checkBoxColumn)
    dgvbool = True
End Sub
```

and this

```
Private Sub P_PRINT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles P_PRINT.Click
    Template.Show()
    Dim message As String = String.Empty
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In D_DATA.Rows
        Dim isSelected As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("checkBoxColumn").Value)
        If isSelected Then
            message += Environment.NewLine
            message += row.Cells("MODEL").Value.ToString()
            Dim txt As New Label
            txt.Text = row.Cells("MODEL").Value
            txt.Location = New Point(50, 50)
            Template.Controls.Add(txt)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You have neglected to ask a question. It is unknown “where” `P_Print_Click` is called from or what `Template` is among other mysteries. The code appears to add a new `Label` control to whatever `Template` is. But what is not working? At first glance it should be obvious that each “newly” added `Label` to `Template` will be placed ON TOP of the previously added `Label` since all the `Labels` are given the same x=50, y=50 `Location` value.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier to just add it to your SQL query. I assume you use SQL Server. DataGridView should generate this as a checkbox column

```
Sub getDataWIP()
    D_DATA.Columns.Clear()
    Dim dt As DataTable = getData("SELECT created_at AS TANGGAL, ASSY_CODE, MODEL, lot_no AS ""LOT NUMBER"", REMARK, QTY, SHIFT, PIC, CAST(0 as BIT) as PRINT FROM WIP_AUTO")
    D_DATA.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Iterate the datatable, not the gridview

```
Private Sub P_PRINT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles P_PRINT.Click
    Template.Show()
    Dim message As String = String.Empty
    For Each row As DataRow In DirectCast(D_DATA.DataSource, DataTable).Rows
        Dim isSelected = row.Field(Of Boolean)("checkBoxColumn")

        If isSelected Then
            Dim mdl = row.Field(Of String)("MODEL")
            message += Environment.NewLine
            message += mdl
            Dim txt As New Label
            txt.Text = mdl
            txt.Location = New Point(50, 50)
            Template.Controls.Add(txt)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I don't know what the point of placing new labels always at the same point 50,50 is